# Finding a TabNavigator tab item with detox in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, detox

I'm using react-navigation in my React Native project that I'm setting up automated testing for using Detox.

Unfortunately, I don't see anything in the docs about how to tell detox to find (and then of course tap) the Tab of a Tab Navigator.

I tried looking through component tree using react-devtools, but couldn't figure out which element represented the tab button itself.

I also tried finding the element by it's text like so:

```
await element(by.text('My Tab Button')).tap();
```

but that through a 'Cannot find UI element' error.

Thanks for any help anyone can offer.

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar issue when using react-navigation in my app. I am currently using react-navigation 2.2.0.

Firstly I tried the following:

```
await element(by.label('Tab Name')).tap();
```

This worked and I was quite happy until I tried a different tab to go to, where the tab name matched a text item on the page, this meant there were two labels with the same text and Detox got confused. So using `by.label` is only useful when you can guarantee that there is one instance of that label on the page.

The way I found to get around this was to set the `tabBarTestID` navigations options for the screen. As long as you use unique ids then there should be no collisions.

Setting the `tabBarTestID` can be done like so in your screen component:

```
class TabScreen extends Component {

  static navigationOptions = () => {
    return {
      title: 'Tab Name',
      tabBarLabel: 'Tab Name',
      tabBarAccessibilityLabel: 'Tab Name',
      tabBarTestID: 'Tab Name',
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor, focused }) => {
        return getTabIcon('Tab Name', focused);
      }
    };
  };

  render () {
    return (
      <View>
       ...
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default TabScreen;
```

This means you should should now be able, in your tests, to use:

`await element(by.id('Tab Name')).tap();`

Comment: Upvoted you but when I tested I was placing "tabBarTestId" inside the screen, when I had to put it in side `createBottomTabNavigator`

Answer (score 1):

In case you are adding in the wrong place, try moving it to `createBottomTabNavigator`

```js
  createBottomTabNavigator(
    {
      YourStackLabel: {
        screen: YourStackNavigator,
        navigationOptions: {
          tabBarTestID: "yourBottomBarButtonTestId",
        },
      },
    }
  );
```

Answer (score -2):

It's all in the docs (almost) 
https://github.com/wix/detox/blob/master/docs/Troubleshooting.RunningTests.md#debug-view-hierarchy

Basically, react native creates a native layout, and Detox is trying to match views from that native layout. In order to examine the layout hierarchy you need to use the tools provided by each platform.

For iOS, use Debug View Hierarchy 
For Android, use [Hierarchy Viewer](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/hierarchy-viewer.html#setup)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, I don't get any options in the Debug -> Attach to Process menu. It stays on "Getting Process List..."(which is grayed out).  Perhaps it makes a difference that I'm launching the Simulator via Expo?

Comment: They are probably supplying a release ipa. can you download a `debug` flavour of expo app ?

Comment: Hi, I'm simply launching the Simulator from Expo, from which I get debugging info in the Expo app or via Chrome Dev tools. There isn't a separate debugging version of Expo.

Comment: Then you'll probably need to create your own app using react-navigation 
(or detach the expo app for a short time) to be able to debug its layout hierarchy